# What's the bijection between reals and infinite sequences of integers?

Tags: set-theory

In Descriptive Set Theory we often see the notion of encoding a real as a sequence of integers or natural numbers -- i.e. there obviously is a bijection according to ZF axioms. But how does it look like concretely? Anybody has seen a simple construction?

My own approach is by chain-fractions:

Let $q\in\mathbb{R}$ be the given real and now define the sequence $(z_i,q_i)$ by $$z_{i+1}=\begin{cases}[q_i]&\text{if } \{q_i\}\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
[q_{i}]+1&\text{else}
\end{cases}$$
$$q_{i+1}=(q_i-z_{i+1})^{-1}$$
where $[q]$ is the next lower integer and $\{q\}=q-[q]$. (Hence $(q_i-z_{i+1})\in(-\frac12,\frac12]$ thereby absolute value of $q_{i+1}$, its reciprocal, is bigger than 2.) Now my bijection is mapping $q$ to the sequence:
$$m_i=\begin{cases}z_i-2&z_i>0, i>1\\
z_i&i=1\\
z_i+2&z_i<0, i>1\end{cases}$$ with $i$ starting at 1 and above $q_0$ becomes the initial $q$. And the inverse of my bijection just calculates the chain-fraction:$q_{i-1}\in(z_i-\frac12,z_i+\frac12]$ with $q_{i-1}=z_i+q_i^{-1}$ step-wise narrowing down the real by a sequence of intervals each containing the next.

is there a paper or book covering my example? any other simple constructions?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56633/simple-bijection-between-reals-and-sets-of-natural-numbers

Comment: Note that in descriptive set theory more often than not "the reals" *are* $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$!

Comment: or elements of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, or elements of ${0,1}^\mathbb{N}$, or indeed any Cantor space, whichever is more convenient at the time.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[**Note:** this answer uses the convention where $\mathbb{N} := \{ 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$ contains zero.]

There's an elegant explicit order-preserving bijection between the [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (under lexicographical order) and $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (under the usual order) described [here](https://oscarcunningham.com/494/a-better-representation-for-real-numbers/).

In particular, we define the image of:

$$ (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots) $$

to be the generalised continued fraction:

$$ a_0 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \ddots}}}} $$

This order-preserving bijection shows that $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are not only isomorphic as sets (i.e. equinumerous), but also isomorphic as totally-ordered sets.

Topologically, this bijection from $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is continuous, meaning that every open subset of the nonnegative reals corresponds to an open subset of Baire space. The converse is not quite true (if it were, the two spaces would be homeomorphic, which they're not); continuity of the inverse map fails exactly at the positive rationals.

Comment: Doesn't this give you the irrationals rather than the full real line?

Comment: It gives you all of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Rationals correspond to sequences that are eventually zero.

Comment: Also, the repeating sequences correspond to the roots of quadratics.

Comment: What you are saying might be right, but it is not mentioned on the wikipedia page that you link to. The page only mentions the homeomorphism if Baire space (with product topology) with the irrationals.

Comment: in fact, the two links in the text go to the same page. maybe you meant to put a different url in the second one?

Comment: Whoops! The second link was meant to go to Oscar Cunningham's blog post: https://oscarcunningham.com/494/a-better-representation-for-real-numbers/

Answer (score 23):

When it comes to relative cardinalities and bijections, the [Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) expresses what in my view is the fundamental fact that cardinal comparisons obey the principle of *anti-symmetry*. Namely, if $|A|\leq|B|$ and $|B|\leq|A|$ then $A$ and $B$ are bijective. That is, if $A$ and $B$ each inject into each other, then the Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem provides a bijection of $A$ with $B$, defined explicitly from those injections. To my way of thinking, it is ultimately this fact that entitles us to think of equinumerosity as a measure of size. (In particular, it is part of my belief that almost every philosophical discussion of [Hume's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hume%27s_principle#:%7E:text=Hume%27s%20principle%20or%20HP%E2%80%94the,systems%20of%20second%2Dorder%20logic.) should be augmented with a discussion of the Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem.)

In your case, there is an easy injection from the reals to infinite sequence of natural numbers, since we can map every real number to the canonical enumeration of the rational numbers below it. And there is an easy injection from the infinite sequences of natural numbers to the reals, by mapping $(n_0,n_1,n_2,\dots)$ to the real number $0.1000\cdots010\cdots010\cdots$, where the number of zeros in each block is $n_0$, $n_1$, and so on.

So the Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem shows that the two sets are equinumerous by the explicit map provided in that proof.

Ultimately, what I am claiming is that it is more important to understand the equinumerosity relation on sets than to try to find a "natural" bijection, which I view as a meaningless concept adding no insight.

Comment: Indeed, the concept of "natural bijection" sounds similar to "canonical bijection", and the bijection here is highly noncanonical.

Comment: My problem with Cantor-Bernstein is it either needs choice or it needs the law of excluded middle. The former is a bad thing in descriptive set theory, while I noticed the latter is heavily used there too. asking for a concrete bijection is a constructive set-theorist move. So you should have guessed that your answer wouldn't be satisfying until you add a paragraph on constructing a bijection from the injection you give from sequences to reals directly since its image is an interval which mathematics can handle directly. Please note that law of excluded middle is absent in some modal logic...

Comment: @user11566470 Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein needs no Choice, only EM cf https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/agda-new/CantorSchroederBernstein.html

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint. It's true, I freely use the law of excluded middle in all mathematical arguments; it is a core part of my conception of mathematical truth.

Comment: *In particular, it is part of my belief that almost every philosophical discussion of Hume's principle should be augmented with a discussion of the Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem.* You've spent too much time at the philosophy department... :-)

Comment: Looking for more concrete maps/bijections between sets (especially definable without AC/LEM) has very tangible payoffs: often those maps turn out to additionally be continuous, or have other good properties.  [Adam Goucher’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/393348/2273) shows that very nicely in this case, giving a continuous bijection $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, which has many descriptive set-theoretic consequences.  The question of what it means for bijections to be “natural” in this way is certainly imprecise, but looking for them absolutely can give real insights.

Comment: I completely agree with Peter that when one has a specific notion of naturality, then there can be big payoffs.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila Historically, there has always been a strong connection between philosophy, logic, and set theory: see works of Russell, Frege, and so on

Answer (score 19):

There are bijections
$$
 \text{Map}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}) \xrightarrow{\alpha}
 \text{Map}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})\setminus\{0\} \xrightarrow{\beta}
 \text{SInc}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}) \setminus\{\text{id}\} \xrightarrow{\gamma}
 \mathcal{P}_\infty(\mathbb{N})\setminus\{\mathbb{N}\} \xrightarrow{\delta} 
 (0,1) \xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathbb{R}
$$
as follows.

1. $\alpha(u)=u$ unless $u$ is constant, in which case $\alpha(u)=u+1$.
2. $\text{SInc}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})$ is the set of strictly increasing maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself, and $\beta(u)(n)=n+\sum_{i\leq n}u(i)$.
3. $\mathcal{P}_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and $\gamma(v)=v(\mathbb{N})$.
4. $\delta(S)=\sum_{i\in S}2^{-i-1}$.
5. $\epsilon(x)=(x-\frac{1}{2})/\sqrt{x(1-x)}$.

We can also give a bijection from $\text{Map}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})$ to the full set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, as follows.  We first note that the rules discussed above also give bijections
$$ \text{Map}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}) \xrightarrow{\beta} 
   \text{SInc}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}) \xrightarrow{\gamma} 
   \mathcal{P}_\infty(\mathbb{N}).
$$
We also have a bijection $\zeta$ from the set $\mathcal{P}_0(\mathbb{N})$ of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ itself given by $\zeta(S)=\sum_{i\in S}2^i$.  Now for $u\in\text{Map}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})$ we define $\eta(u)\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})=\mathcal{P}_0(\mathbb{N})\amalg\mathcal{P}_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ by
$$ \eta(u) = \begin{cases}
    \zeta^{-1}(n) & \text{ if } u \text{ is constant with value } 2n \\
    \gamma\beta(n) & \text{ if } u \text{ is constant with value } 2n+1 \\ 
    \gamma\beta(u) & \text{ if } u \text{ is not constant. }
   \end{cases}
$$
This gives a bijection $\eta\colon\text{Map}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Do you want $\alpha$? I think $\beta$ maps the zero sequence to the identity function.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes, $\beta(0)=\text{id}$ and $\gamma(\text{id})=\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta(\mathbb{N})=1$, so I have to use $\alpha$ if I want the codomain to be $(0,1)$ rather than $(0,1]$.